# how to show data related to selected checkbox in grid

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

one dropdown list, from and to date and search button.
when user select value from dropdown list select date and press search button user can view data in grid according to the selected field till now i have completed my project now what i want is when i select a checkbox to show data related to particular column in the gridview in bulk suppose i have 50 user and 25 are from delhi city now i want when user select checkbox it can only view delhi user in the grid how can i do that..thanks in advance
[image]

```
protected void Chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Chk.Checked!=null)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection con;
        if (ddlPortal2.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bart;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Form3 where Portal='" + ddlPortal2.SelectedValue + "' and Query=Query", con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

OnCheckedChanged="EventHandler"

event on the checkbox and fill the Gridview inside the event

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. If you don't mind a postback, then you can set `autopostback` for the control. Then you can handle the `checked` event on the server side, filter the dataset and redind the grid. If you would like to avoid a postback, you can use AJAX to do this. But this will be more complex and if you are already using an asp.net datagrid, the server-side rout is much more inline with the webforms methodology.